# Reversing Logic in SQL Query

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL query and I'm unsure about how to reverse its logic to remove the negation.

```sql
SELECT id, title
FROM books
WHERE books.deleted_at is null
  AND NOT (books.publication_date > :publicationDate OR (books.publication_date = :publicationDate AND books.publication_time > :publicationTime))
  AND NOT (books.reprint_date < :reprintDate OR (books.reprint_date = :reprintDate AND books.reprint_time < :reprintTime));
```

I came up with this query, but in some cases, it doesn't return the same results as the original query above.

```sql
SELECT id, title
FROM books
WHERE books.deleted_at is null
  AND (books.publication_date < :publicationDate OR (books.publication_date = :publicationDate AND books.publication_time < :publicationTime))
  AND (books.reprint_date > :reprintDate OR (books.reprint_date = :reprintDate AND books.reprint_time > :reprintTime));
```

I would like to know if the inversion of the logical operators is correct, and I also want to know if in these cases the OR and AND operators should be inverted as well.

Comment: There is at least one problem. You're forgetting about the "equal to"-values. In both cases you're only checking for dates bigger/smaller than the other one. None of the conditions include `>=` or `<=`.